# How to make multiple dataframe using for loop or any other method..?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I really Thx for everyone helping me.
I made 25 dataframes by my hand..
but, in my opinion, there are some method to reducing the code by for loop or anyother.

this is my code.

here are sample dataframe.

==================================================================
NO      ITEM     meaningless num  col1     col2     col3

```
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.318  0.338  0.338 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.318  0.318  0.338 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 mon_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.318  0.338  0.338 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.318  0.318  0.338 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2295 tue_BB_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.318  0.338  0.338 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2296 tue_AA_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2297 tue_FF_2nd_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.338  0.318  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_3bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  01  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  02  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  03  0.338  0.338  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  04  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  05  0.338  0.318  0.338 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  06  0.318  0.318  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  07  0.338  0.338  0.318 
 2298 wed_E0_16bit_MAX_ XXXXXXX  08  0.338  0.338  0.338 

day = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed','thu','fri']
jjj = ['AA','BB','C3','FF','E0','DD']
kkk= ['3bit','2bit','4bit','8bit','16bit']


a1 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[0]))].astype(float)
a2 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[1]))].astype(float)
a3 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[2]))].astype(float)
a4 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[3]))].astype(float)
a5 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[4]))].astype(float)
a6 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[1])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[0]))].astype(float)
a7 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[1])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[1]))].astype(float)
a8 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[1])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[2]))].astype(float)
a9 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[1])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[3]))].astype(float)
a10 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[1])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[4]))].astype(float)
a11 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[2])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[0]))].astype(float)
a12 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[2])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[1]))].astype(float)
a13 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[2])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[2]))].astype(float)
a14 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[2])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[3]))].astype(float)
a15 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[2])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[4]))].astype(float)
a16 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[0]))].astype(float)
a17 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[1]))].astype(float)
a18 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[2]))].astype(float)
a19 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[3]))].astype(float)
a20 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[4]))].astype(float)
a21 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[0]))].astype(float)
a22 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[1]))].astype(float)
a23 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[2]))].astype(float)
a24 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[3]))].astype(float)
a25 = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[0])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[3])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[4]))].astype(float)




for i in range(25):
  for j in day : 
     for k in jjj:
       for l in kkk :
  a'i' = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(day[j])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(jjj[k])) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(kkk[l]))].astype(float)
```

like this...? Sorry for my bad coding..

Comment: Can you add to your question an example of what some of the dataframes look like?

Comment: okay i will do that.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(df['ITEM'].head().tolist())` please? And what is 'day', 'jjj' and 'kkk'?

Comment: day and kkk are just name of list, meaningless..

Comment: And i want to make 25 dataframes, not only one merged dataframe... :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Something like

```
days = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"]
hexes = ["AA", "BB", "C3", "FF", "E0", "DD"]
bits = ["3bit", "2bit", "4bit", "8bit", "16bit"]

sub_dfs = {}

for day in days:
    day_df = df[df["ITEM"].str.contains(day)]
    for hex in hexes:
        hex_df = day_df[day_df["ITEM"].str.contains(hex)]
        for bit in bits:
            bit_df = hex_df[hex_df["ITEM"].str.contains(bit)]
            sub_dfs[(day, hex, bit)] = bit_df
```

should generate you a dictionary of day-hex-bit triples to the "sub-dataframe" of that combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loops to iterate over all the different combinations of `day`, `jjj`, and `kkk`, and create a dataframe for each combination.

```
day = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed','thu','fri']
jjj = ['AA','BB','C3','FF','E0','DD']
kkk= ['3bit','2bit','4bit','8bit','16bit']

dfs = []
for d in day:
    for j in jjj:
        for k in kkk:
            df_temp = df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(d)) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(j)) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(k))].astype(float)
            dfs.append(df_temp)
```

This code will create a list of dataframes called `dfs`, where each dataframe corresponds to a unique combination of `day`, `jjj`, and `kkk`. You can access each dataframe using its index in the `list`, like `dfs[0]`, `dfs[1]`, etc.

If you want to give each dataframe a unique variable name instead of storing them in a list, you can use dictionary comprehension like this:

```
day = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed','thu','fri']
jjj = ['AA','BB','C3','FF','E0','DD']
kkk= ['3bit','2bit','4bit','8bit','16bit']

dfs = {f"a{i}": df[(df['ITEM'].str.contains(d)) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(j)) & (df['ITEM'].str.contains(k))].astype(float)
       for i, d in enumerate(day, start=1)
       for j in jjj
       for k in kkk}
```

This will create a dictionary with keys like `a1`, `a2`, `etc`., where each key corresponds to a unique combination of `day`, `jjj`, and `kkk`. You can access each dataframe using its key in the `dictionary`, like `dfs['a1']`, `dfs['a2']`, etc.